# Convert structure of columns in list of dataframes to character in R

Tags: r, lapply

I'm creating an empty list of dataframes that I will append later using lapply.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

my.list <- lapply(1:192, function(x, nr = 468, nc = 1) {   data.frame(symbol = matrix(nrow=nr, ncol=nc)) })
str(my.list)
```

If you obtain the structure of my.list you will notice that the structure of the columns within each dataframe is "logical".  I would like the structure of the column in each dataframe to be character rather than logical.

Can I change anything within my lapply function above so that the columns in the resulting list of dataframes are character?  Or how best would I go about this task? I'm creating this empty list of dataframes because I understand that R works faster if it doesn't have to constantly append files.  Thus my next step is to perform a map function to populate each dataframe in this list of dataframes with character data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue would be that by creating `NA`, by default it is `NA_logical_`.  If we want to create a character column, use `NA_character_`.  Here, we can fix with

```
my.list <- lapply(my.list, function(x) {x[] <- lapply(x, as.character); x})
```

---

Or while creating the `data.frame` column, use

```
my.list <- lapply(1:192, function(x) data.frame(symbol = rep(NA_character_, 468)))
```

The `matrix` route to get a single column `data.frame` is not ideal and is sometimes incorrect (because `matrix` can have only a single class whereas `data.frame` columns can be of different type).  The easiest option is `rep`licate the `NA_character_` with `n` times to create a single column `data.frame` with `n` rows