# Homogenizing columns when merging using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

I am reading some datasets that I read year-by-year. I have saved them as `dyyc` where `y` is a year variable that ranges from `00` to `11`. I am trying to merge all these files into one with the following code:

```
list_of_data = list(d00c,d01c,d02c,d03c,d04c,d05c,d06c,d07c,d08c,d09c,d10c,d11c)
names(list_of_data) = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011)

## Combine it
library(dplyr)
bigd = bind_rows(list_of_data, .id = "year")
```

This is giving me problems as it turns out that, for instance `d00c$id` is numeric while `d05c$id`  is a character. This actually happens with a lot of identifying codes. A brute force way to solve it would be to precede the code above with:

```
> d00c$id<-as.character(d00c$id)
.
.
.
> d11c$id<-as.character(d11c$id)
```

but this is a bit tedious. This seems like something that could more easily resolved using `lapply`, but I am not sure how to since it involves affecting columns from all the data.frames in question. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: is d00c a dataframe or a named list? Can you run dput(d00c)?

Comment: Just read it using read.csv, but it is actually a list.

Comment: You might find this useful: [Convert structure of columns in list of dataframes to character in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66680499/convert-structure-of-columns-in-list-of-dataframes-to-character-in-r) - good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your data. I am going to create a list of data frames where the `id` column is sometimes `character` and sometimes and `numeric`:

```r
dat  <- data.frame(id = 1:3, char = letters[1:3])
dat_list  <- lapply(1:5, \(i) 
    if(i%%2==0) dat else transform(dat, id = as.character(id))
)
names(dat_list)  <- 2000:2004
```

We can simply iterate over this with `lapply()`, as you suggested, mutating `id` to a `character` vector in all cases, and then `bind_rows()`:

```r
dat_list  |> 
    lapply(\(dat) mutate(dat, id = as.character(id)))  |>
    bind_rows(.id = "year") 
#    year id char
# 1  2000  1    a
# 2  2000  2    b
# 3  2000  3    c
# 4  2001  1    a
# 5  2001  2    b
# # <etc>
```

If it is not just the `id` column which has mixed types, you can use convert all columns to `character`, and then convert them back based on their contents:

```r
dat_list  |> 
    lapply(\(dat) mutate(dat, across(everything(), as.character)))  |>
    bind_rows(.id = "year")  |>
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

This is risky though as your final types depend on your data, e.g. in this case `id` will end up `numeric` rather than `character`, which may be desirable, but is not reliable.

#### base R approach

You can alternatively achieve the same thing in base R using `do.call(rbind, dat_list)`, which does not strictly enforce types. It will also automatically import the list names as row names. Annoyingly, they have the row number appended to make them unique (e.g. `2000.1` rather than `2000`), so you need to edit them a little:

```r
do.call(rbind, dat_list)  |>
    tibble::rownames_to_column("year")  |>
    mutate(year = substr(year, 1, 4))
```

Be careful with using `do.call(rbind, dat_list)` if you are not sure of all your types, as it may silently coerce columns other than `id`.

Comment: Thanks @SamR, great solution! I like the first approach, but the problem is I do not really have a dat file, since each d00c-d11c file has a common number of columns, but also some have extra ones, and getting a dat equivalent would imply already dealing with my original problem, right?

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez I thought your problem was different column types, rather than different number of columns. See how to make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to avoid such misunderstandings. Nevertheless, `bind_rows()` will work if there are extra columns, filling the missing values with `NA`. Is that not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
list_of_data <- lapply(list_of_data, function(x) {
  x$id <- as.character(x$id)
  x
})
```

Which, for my example data, gives the output:

```
$`2000`
$`2000`$id
[1] "1" "2" "3"

$`2000`$value
[1] 4 5 6


$`2005`
$`2005`$id
[1] "hello world!" "hi again"     "bye!"        

$`2005`$value
[1] 7 8 9
```

The data:

```
d00c <- list(id = 1:3, value = 4:6)
d05c <- list(id = c("hello world!", "hi again", "bye!"), value = 7:9)

list_of_data = list(`2000` = d00c, `2005` = d05c)
```